How do I add a while statement that works after a if and elif statement is done?
I added an if and elif statment, and I'm trying to make it so that when my while statement is fulfilled, my code continues.
I'm making a turn-based PVP game, still at the begginer tutorial part of it, and somehow my code isn't working.
I add a variable that makes the groof's hp = 10.
So, when the user inputs ("attack") the enemy loses 10 hp. Simple. Then I add a
while groofhp == 0:
Whatever goes here:
But the if and elif statements work perfectly fine(In every case the groof loses 10hp) but whenever the HP hits 0, the code just stops running there.

 print("A wild groof has spawned. Pick a card to attack. Element and ATTACK.")
 groofpvpturn1 = input("What card shall you pick to start the fight?")
 if groofpvpturn1 in ("ATTACK", "Attack", "attack"):
    print( + charactername + "has hit the groof! The groof lost 5hp!")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Pick another card.")
    if groofpvpturn1 in ("ATTACK", "Attack", "attack"):
       groof1hp - 5
    elif groofpvpturn1 in ("ELEMENT", "element", "Element"):
        groofhp - 5
    
 elif groofpvpturn1 in ("Element", "element", "ELEMENT"):
      print(""+ charactername + " has used ELEMENT on the groof! The groof lost 10 hp!")
      groof1hp - 10
      while groof1hp == 0:
            print("You have defeated the groof. GG!")



you're doing an operation on groof1hp but not saving the result

None of your groof1hp - x statements change the value of groof1hp; they simply produce (and ignore) the value of the expression.

The while loop should contain the if/elif statement, so that you can make repeated attacks until groof1hp < 0 is true.

I had little hard time understanding the very essence of the question, so I changed a logic a bit and fixed it to the way I saw it. explanation is down below in comments. if you'll have further questions please comment. hope it helps.
    #setup I assume you have another implementation but I'm mocking it here
    charactername = "Stackoverflow"
    print("A wild groof has spawned. Pick a card to attack. Element and ATTACK.\n") 
    groof1hp = 10

    #starting with first call printing once
    print("What card shall you pick to start the fight?\n")
    while groof1hp > 0: #loop works till groof's health drops below 0 (till hp<=0)
        groofpvpturn1 = input("Pick a card.\n") 
        if groofpvpturn1 in ("ATTACK", "Attack", "attack"):
            groof1hp -= 5 # updating groofs's health is the must. otherwise hp wont 
                          #update it will just calculate and wont be saved
            print("" + charactername + "has hit the groof! The groof lost 5hp!")
    
        elif groofpvpturn1 in ("Element", "element", "ELEMENT"):
            groof1hp -= 10 #update hp
            print(""+ charactername + " has used ELEMENT on the groof! The groof lost 10 hp!")
    
    #I changed a logic a bit to not exatly killing it when hp == 0 but any attack 
    #elemental or not which takes it to 0 or below will kill Mr groof  
    print("You have defeated the groof. GG!")


Thanks, it helped. I'll just reflect to this whenever I'm making a code like this anytime. No  questions.
